# Exception: krb_error 0 Do not have keys of types listed in default_tkt_enctypes

Tags: encryption, sso, kerberos

I am looking for your help with one Exception we are getting while setting up our Kerberos SSO. I will briefly give an overview of our setup and things we tried till now and exception we are getting:

1. Our setup has One KDC server (RNDLABDC6.EXAMPLE.DOMAIN.COM) and 2 Client Machine (VMUSER01.EXAMPLE.DOMAIN.COM and VMUSER02.EXAMPLE.DOMAIN.COM) 
   We have a service user in KDC “user01”  mapped to SPN “HTTP/VMUSER01” (setspn -U -A HTTP/USER01.EXAMPLE.DOMAIN.COM@EXAMPLE.DOMAIN.COM sparta\user01
2. ).
   Created keytab file for user “filename.keytatb” (ktpass -princ HTTP/VMUSER01.EXAMPLE.DOMAIN.COM@EXAMPLE.DOMAIN.COM -mapuser user01@EXAMPLE.DOMAIN.COM -mapOp set -pass Sell.it -crypto all -kvno 0 -ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL -out filename.keytatb ).
3. “Kinit user01@filename.keytatb  password “ works fine and we get a ticket back from KDC.
4. Kinit –k –t  filename.keytab user01@filename.keytatb  gives us below error

Exception: krb_error 0 Do not have keys of types listed in default_tkt_enctypes
available; only have keys of following type:  No error
KrbException: Do not have keys of types listed in default_tkt_enctypes available

We tried creating keytab file with multilple encrytpions but all results in same error.

Contents from my Krb.ini files are :

[libdefaults]
default_realm = EXAMPLE.DOMAIN.COM
default_tkt_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96 des3-cbc-sha1 arcfour-hmac-md5 rc4-hmac des3-hmac-sha1 camellia256-cts-cmac camellia128-cts-cmac des-cbc-crc des-cbc-md5 des-cbc-md4
default_tgs_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96 des3-cbc-sha1 arcfour-hmac-md5 rc4-hmac des3-hmac-sha1 camellia256-cts-cmac camellia128-cts-cmac des-cbc-crc des-cbc-md5 des-cbc-md4
dns_lookup_kdc = true
dns_lookup_realm = true

[realms]
SPARTA.RNDLAB.LOC = {
    kdc = RNDLABDC6.EXAMPLE.DOMAIN.COM
    admin_server = RNDLABDC6.EXAMPLE.DOMAIN.COM
    master_kdc = RNDLABDC6.EXAMPLE.DOMAIN.COM
    default_domain = EXAMPLE.DOMAIN.COM
}

[domain_realm]
.EXAMPLE.DOMAIN.COM = EXAMPLE.DOMAIN.COM

[logging]
kdc = SYSLOG:INFO
admin_server = FILE=c:\kadm5.log

Let me know if any further info is required here.

Comment: Did you solved the issue

Comment: I had the same error when I had my keytab file in a path with a space in it (```C:\Program Files\blah```) and I hadn't wrapped the path in double quotes when using ```kinit```.  I can see this is not the solution for you but it might help someone else, so I'm adding it as a comment.